# Querying between two tables that share an association

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

New to seqeul and sql in general. I have two tables, `groups` and `resources`, that are associated `many_to_many` and therefore have a `groups_resources` join table. I also have a `task` table that has a `foreign_key :group_id, :groups` and is associated `many_to_one` with groups.

I'm trying to figure out what query to use that will allow my to get the resources that are able to do a task, based on a task's group. Do I have to do a complicated query via the `groups_resources' join table, or is there a more straightforward query/ way of setting up my associations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure the SQL statement as below. Which would provide you the resources objects that are associated with a specific task id through the join table.

```
SELECT r.*
FROM resources r
JOIN groups_resources gr ON gr.resources_id = r.id
JOIN groups g ON gr.group_id = g.id
JOIN task t ON t.id = g.id
WHERE t.id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following is enough:

```
select res.* from resources res, task tk, groups_resources gr
where res.resource_id = gr.resource_id and
gr.group_id = tk.group_id and
tk.group_id=<>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are helpful for how to structure a SQL query, but thought I would answer my own question specifically as it relates to Sequel. Turns out there is a `many_through_many` plugin that makes this sort of querying simple, if you make both tables `many_to_many` :

```
Task.plugin :many_through_many
Task.many_through_many :resources,
  :through =>[
    [:groups_tasks, :task_id, :group_id],
    [:groups, :id, :id],
    [:groups_resources, :group_id, :resource_id]
  ]
```

Now you can just call something like `task.resources` on a `Task` instance, even though your tables don't explicitly associate tasks and resources.